# SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js

I searched for a similar question on google and the similar questions but to no help.

```
// file export_object.js

function Welcome(nameIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
}

Welcome.prototype = {
    this.name = null,
    showName: function () {
        console.log("Hi exported object from contructor function " + name);
    },
    updateName: function(nameIn) {
        this.name = nameIn;
    }
};

module.exports = Welcome;
```

The problem is on the line

> this.name = null,

```
// file server.js

var Welcome = require('export_object');
var w = new Welcome("Please update string");
w.updateName('Exported name:');
w.showName();
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

Comment: Instead of voting down, or cutting somebody a leg, could you please let me know why there is something wrong instead? I am sure it would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is already assigned in the constructor, so explicitly defining an empty property in the prototype doesn't make sense. Just remove that line:

```
function Welcome(nameIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
}

Welcome.prototype = {
    showName: function () {
        console.log("Hi exported object from contructor function " + name);
    },
    updateName: function(nameIn) {
        this.name = nameIn;
    }
};

module.exports = Welcome;
```

If you *had* to put a name property on the prototype, the proper way to define a key-value pair is to separate them with a colon, eg

```
{
  name: null,
```

Which would make the syntax proper, but would still be pretty odd to do in most situations.

Comment: The thing is this example is straight from a book. There is no errata yet though. Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Then that book is definitely wrong - their syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Because  here `Welcome.prototype`  is an Object

so an object is always define as {"key":"value"}, so your syntax is wrong

```
function Welcome(nameIn) {
    this.name = nameIn;
}

Welcome.prototype = {
    resetName: function(){ this.name = null},
    showName: function () {
        console.log("Hi exported object from contructor function " + name);
    },
    updateName: function(nameIn) {
        this.name = nameIn;
    }
};

module.exports = Welcome;
```